# Custom column names on Django ManyToMany fields

Tags: django, model, django-admin, customization, django-orm

I am building a UI for a java application in django. I want to create Java tables according to the ones created by JPA. For this when i use the ManyToMany Field, the newly created intermediate table has column names which are not matching the ones with the JPA.

Is there any way that i can give custom names to the columns in the table So, as to not get the Missing column error in Java.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify a custom [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) model without specifying any extra fields. Then you can use `db_column=...` in the `ForeignKey` fields:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A, through='C', db_table='customtablename')

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, db_column='customcolumnname')
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, db_column='secondcustomcolumnname')
```

Comment: Thanks for it. But i did add a few things for the display which i think would be essential when using 'through'

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to create the "through" model? I am trying to have a custom foreign key column in the ManyToMany intermediary table. Is there a way to make ManyToManyField take db_column as an argument?

Comment: @klandshome There's always a way. Is there a good way? Definitely not. You *could* set `db_column` directly on `<Model>.<m2m_field>.through.<fk_field>` after the model definition (e.g. the `class_prepared` signal) but there's no guarantee that some other code won't use the model before the change.

Comment: `toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, db_table='pizza_link_topping')`
Is this example fine though? I mean it works and does allow the intermediary table to have the custom name, pizza_link_table.  Just couldn't get it to work with the a custom foreign key column..

Comment: In other words, `through` is the most "elegant" way? Is it worth using it just to get a custom foreign key column?

Comment: I found that setting `column` directly on `<Model>.<m2m_field>.through.<fk_field>.field` after the model definition worked on Django v1.8. I needed to do it this way as Django admin didn't support ManyToManyField fields with a manually set through model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this using the [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) parameter.

This looks like: `my_m2m_field=models.ManytoManyField(Model, db_name="Desired Name")`

Comment: I tried using this as well and db_column also, but it in no way changes the column name.

Comment: @Akshay Have you deleted the generated table and runned `syncdb` again? Django can't alter existent tables by itself.

Comment: Yes, i always delete the existing tables after making some changes in the code for testing. So far tyried a lot of different approaches but no success. I feel it has to be something very trivial.

Comment: I think you confused the `db_column` and `db_name` parameters. There seems to be no possibility to change the column names of a many_to_many relationship without using a through table. There you could indeed use the db_column param but using the db_name param has no effect on the column names

Answer (score 0):

As knbk mentioned above it is indeed the way out, Below is the complete way i have done it.

```
class A(models.Model):
....

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A,through = 'C', db_table = 'customtablename')

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A,db_column='customcolumnname')
    b = models.ForeignKey(B,db_column='secondcustomcolumnname')
```

After this for displaying it on the admin console, you have to use inlines so that both the models can be changes simultaneously.(which i think is again a matter of choice/requirement).The way to do this is,

In admin.py

```
class ABInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = B.a.through

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ABInline,]

class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ABInline,]
    exclude = ('a',)
```

admin.register.site(B,BAdmin)

This model can be registered in which ever model you want.